# Getting an application's name - ignoring local

Tags: android, localization

I'm trying to pull the name of applications installed on an Android device:

```
String applicationLabel = _packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString();
// The name can be null (apparently).
applicationLabel = applicationLabel == null ? UNKNOWN : applicationLabel;
return applicationLabel;
```

The problem with `getApplicationLabel` is that it uses the local of the device and it returns the localized name (see [snippet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java#935))

I don't want the local name, I want the default value stored under /values/string.xml

Any idea how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want your `applicationLabel` as value stored in string.xml .. check out below..

Suppose `app_lab` is your label stored in string.xml then...

```
//String applicationLabel = _packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString();
String applicationLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.app_lab);
// The name can be null (apparently).
applicationLabel = applicationLabel == null ? UNKNOWN : applicationLabel;
return applicationLabel;
```

Comment: That's fine in case you are trying to get your own label. How do I do it for other applications ?